# How best to control (issue command signals to) a PHP-based Daemon script?

Tags: php, daemon, command

I've created a PHP Daemon script to continually monitor a particular directory on the server's file system for new files, and then process and archive them.

***Note:** I'm using a php Daemon class provided at:
 http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/8958.html*

I've got the script running, but I need a way to interface with the daemon and issue commands. One really useful command, for instance, would be "STOP"! :) I currently have to kill the process manually.

I've done this before using control files (i.e., check the file for a new command, execute it if one exists, then clear the file). I've also used sockets, but this problem doesn't really call for any networking. Is there a better, more elegant or natural way to send command signals to the Daemon?

I did find this:
[PHP Daemon/worker environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752214/php-daemon-worker-environment)
But I'm afraid I don't fully grasp how to use the provided code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution would be to use signals -- see [`pcntl_signal`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php), for instance : your PHP daemon would listen for signals, and you'd only have to send signals from "outside".

That's a way that is quite often used on UNIX/Linux -- but note that `pcntl_*` functions will not be available on windows. *(The class you posted is already using `pcntl*` functions, so nothing new here)*

Answer (score 2):

On *nix you can use signals to control your daemon; see[`pcntl_signal()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php) and the `signal(7)` man page.