# PHP COM object is shared

Tags: php, .net, multithreading, com, garbage-collection

A client is using PHP as follows:

```
function getBlah($something) {
  $p1 = "foo";
  $p2 = "bar";
  $obj = new COM("namespace.class");
  $result = $obj->method($p1,$p2,$something);
  unset($obj);
  $blah = explode(chr(10),$result); // and do other stuff
  echo $blah;
}
```

The COM object is a VB.NET class. This code works. The PHP is getting executed from a web page.

Within the .NET method another class is instantiated which does communications with a server. On completion of the method, we "assume" the .NET garbage collection is going to dispose all resources. We further "assume" that on completion of the PHP method that the COM object will get wrapped up through PHP GC and that those resources will not be available to other processes.

But we're finding that as multiple users hit the function simultaneously that threads instantiated within the .NET method objects are being re-used. So user1 executes the PHP, the COM object is instantiated and the method called, a managed object is created, that object creates at thread and waits for a server response for some milliseconds to seconds. Now user2 does the same but somehow user1's response comes back on user2's thread. So either or both processes return, and one of them might have the response from the other's thread!

Yeah, we all know what "assume" means, and we've tried explicit resource disposal in every way possible.

Another question here expresses the exact opposite problem : [Is it possible to cache/serialize a COM object in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164096/is-it-possible-to-cache-serialize-a-com-object-in-php) The responses to that say No but this might prove otherwise.

Reproducing this can be very difficult but the fact that it occurs once in a while is very irritating - imagine submitting a web form and getting a confirmation for someone else's transaction - not good eh?

While the scope of a PHP variable is unique to each process, and each process GC's its own resources at the end of each function, it seems like the memory allocated for COM objects is in some way shared while two users are executing the same code. In other words, a PHP function that includes a COM object does not appear to be re-entrant.

Can anyone point to some rules to confirm that this is defined behavior, or that this is a verifiable bug?
Is PHP over Windows recognized as not being thread-safe?
Is there some flag that needs to be set or some patch to apply to ensure thread-safe stability?
Do we need to use semaphores or blocking locks?
Is there some issue or known configuration for Fast-CGI or IIS7?

I don't have the PHP version handy and need to get details on the exact environment. Please forgive some missing details, but if you know something is significant please ask. (Um, and please don't ask if the answer doesn't change your response.) I'm also more of a .NET guy than a PHP guy, so I could be missing something else critical here or obvious to a PHP guru.

And yes, I've been looking for answers to some of these questions for months, but having no luck with Google or here at SO. So here we are.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you use a semaphore to lock the the COM object so it doesn't get used concurrently?

Comment: "Is PHP over Windows recognized as not being thread-safe?" There are thread-safe and non-thread-safe windows builds for php.  Not sure if a thread-safe build will avoid these issues for you though.

Comment: @Petah, using a semaphore (static property, etc) is an option, but it will throttle the site. Thanks.

Comment: @Danny, I'm aware that we'll have to do the research to identify, for example, a thread-safe v5.3, where php.ini has paramX=foo and Fast-CGI is turned off, except where IIS7 has some specific application pool value. I'm hoping to get something more specific. Thanks.